# simulate an "<a href>" in Angular

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have a situation (modal popup) that classical link using `<a href>` does not work, so I need to simulate that link behavior in a `<div>`.
[CODEPEN link](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/OXJqWO?editors=1011)

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('testCtrl', ['$scope', '$window', function($scope, $window) {
  $scope.greeting = 'Hola!';
  $scope.myAlert = function(event) {
    console.log('this is the $scope.greeting');
    console.log($scope.greeting);
    console.log('this is the $window.location.href:');
    console.log($window.location.href);
    console.log('this is the event.target.dataset.href:');
    console.log(event.target.dataset.href);   
    $window.location.href = event.target.dataset.href;
  }
}]);
```

```html
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="testCtrl">
  <div data-href="http://test.com" ng-click="myAlert($event);">CLICK ME!</div>
  <div ng-click="$window.location.href='http://test.com';">DIRECTT LINK!</div>
</div>
```

**Why the second div does nothing on click ?**

**NB.**

I don't need to open the link in the popup or the new widow, my div is already in a popup, so I need just to open that link in the same widow like an `a href` does, is all I need.

In other words, I need to open a link without using a "a href". The URL is in the generated HTML, so I can't put the url in the javascript, that is an independent file...

Comment: *"using <a href> does not work"* ... why not? Should work fine

Comment: @charlietfl, in several cases the modal angular window that uses a template, the "a href" does not work, but the question isn't in that...

Comment: Do you need the end result to be a modal opening the info in that link?

Comment: I need just to open the link in the same window, like a href does..

Comment: Something like this? http://codepen.io/gabrielhobold/pen/LZYaKy?editors=1011

Comment: @GabrielHobold, thanks, but see my edit in the OP..

Comment: @cale_b, OP may mean ***poster*** OR ***post***, cf https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OP

Answer (score 2):

Your code is not working because html does not recognises $window
Try this in html

```
    <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="testCtrl">
      <div data-href="http://test.com" ng-click="myAlert($event);">CLICK ME!</div>
      <div ng-click="openLink('http://test.com');">DIRECTT LINK!</div>
    </div>
```

in script:

```
    var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

    myApp.controller('testCtrl', ['$scope', '$window', function($scope, $window) {
      $scope.greeting = 'Hola!';
      $scope.myAlert = function(event) {
        console.log('this is the $scope.greeting');
        console.log($scope.greeting);
        console.log('this is the $window.location.href:');
        console.log($window.location.href);
        console.log('this is the event.target.dataset.href:');
        console.log(event.target.dataset.href);   
        $window.location.href = event.target.dataset.href;
      }

      $scope.openLink = function(link){
        $window.location.href = link;
      };

    }]);
```

Comment: I have no acces to link in the javascript. I need to take it from HTML... HTML does not recognize the "$window" object, this should do the Angular, cause this is an angular directive "ng-click", isn't it?!

Comment: how are you getting the link in html and not in the controller?

Comment: I generate the HTML using server scripting.

Comment: AngularJS template can only see what is available in scope and not a service that you are injecting into a controller, You will have to pass $window to $scope or $rootScope in order to use it as it is in template

Comment: tried `$scope.myWindow = $window;`, does not work... (

Comment: for $window, angularJS has an exception, it does not allow window object to be accessible in the template, though $location can be binded to scope and accessed inside template, but $location is used for internal navigation only

Comment: when using $location I have problems with the browser's history, it does not navigate back correctly. As for the using of a function in ng-click, I already do it in the first link... this is why I already reference that first example link, I wonder why the second does not work...

Answer (score 0):

use `<div onclick="window.location.replace('http://test.com')"></div>`

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I know in Angular is better to use $window instead of javascript "window" directly... https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$window

Comment: You should use Angular's `$window` wrapper

Comment: @Serge - `$window` is not always available in all contexts.  If you notice, it was `injected` into the controller in the docs you linked to.  Follow the pattern where the `ng-click` fires a controller function, and reference `$window` within the controller.